# Soundplayer wpf

Tags: wpf, soundplayer

I'm trying to play 2 songs in total, one after another. This is my code now using C# for WPF.
Any advice?

```
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Open(new Uri(@"C:\Users\L31006\Desktop\Window Wipe\welcome.mp3"));
        player.Play();
```

Comment: There is no question mark. What is your  problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the [`MediaEnded`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.mediaended%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of `player`. This is where you would start the second song.